# EntityGraph and JoinFormula

Tags: hibernate

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.12 and Hibernate 5.6.15.Final and I have the following entity configuration

```
public class TaskEntity {
   ...
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinFormula("my query")
   private AnotherEntity anotherEntity;
}
```

Inside the TaskRepository I need to create a query in which "anotherEntity" is loaded in order to avoid n+1 queries. I have tried with the @EntityGraph in the following way

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"anotherEntity"})
@Query("from TaskEntity t")
List<TaskEntity> searchTaskAssignments();
```

but it's not working.
How can I fetch a @JoinFormula field in order to avoid n+1 queries?